# distributed system programming with php

Tags: php, mysql, distributed

I'm doing a system for a hospital in my country as the final year project of my degree, my supervisor specially asked me to use php and mysql for this. i don't have any experience with distributed systems and php programming, can any one help me out to build my base and improove my knowledge stating some sites, books to refer to overcome this matter.

regards,
rangana.

Comment: Distributed? PHP? HOSPITAL? I see a lot of people die in the future.

Comment: don't know buddy, i don't know how these things cope up with each other but, only thing i know is, he asked me to refer about distributed systems, and do it using php and mysql??? please clear me on this matter???

Comment: PHP has gotten a really bad reputation. It's insecure and really easy to introduce mistakes that are hard to find with. If you google for PHP tutorials, you will find tons of ressource on PHP itself, as it's immensly popular because it's so easy (the consequence of that is what you can read in my second sentence.). Most tutorials cover MySQL too, because PHP has support for MySQL built in.

Comment: @rangana I think your supervisor needs to clarify what exactly they mean by "distributed".

Comment: @LukeN The fact that PHP is a (sometimes too) permissive language and has a great semi-professional following does not mean it is not possible to develop highly secure, stable, professional software in it. (I still laughed about your 1st comment :). If the word "distributed" is anything serious, though, the standard run-off-the-mill PHP tutorial isn't going to cut it.

Comment: Is the "supervisor" in charge of the hospital or your degree program?

Comment: @Pekka Of course it is possible to write high secure and reliable software with PHP, but so is it with assembler and brainf*ck :) I just think I'll never understand what's going on in the average "supervisor's" head. They never seem to know what they're talking about ;)

Comment: @LukeN I see what you mean but I have to disagree. PHP 5 and - among other things - QA tools like PHPUnit and other notable tools by Sebastian Bergmann (http://sebastian-bergmann.de/software/) make it possible to work with PHP in a very, very high-level way. The fact that PHP doesn't enforce that way from the start is both its charm and its curse - you can still see its templating language roots there, no doubt. Still, PHP is fine if handled correctly. You just shouldn't *learn programming* with PHP alone IMO.

Answer (score 6):

I'm guessing you want something like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider the literature on the following topic:

- 3 Tier Application Architectures (or N-tier in general)

Tiers in general would be the DataStore (an RDBMs usually), the Business Logic Layer and the Presentation Layer.

Each layer can be examined and analyzed thoroughly, depending on your needs and solutions such as Load Balancing, Workload Distribution (in a sometimes clustered environment), Database Clustering/Replication/Splitting, might be needed.

Good luck with your project.

Comment: thank you very much for your valuable comments and suggestions guys, i highly appreciate it, thanks again...!